# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details

Tags: android

I created an alphabets app. I used 26 audio files. Files extension are `.amr`. The name of these files are `m1.amr` to `m26.amr`. 
In emulator everything is working fine but
when I create signed apk, I have a lot of errors

[image]

Part of code is given below. I used array for audio files, and keep it in raw directory

```
private static final int [] media_ids =
{
R.raw.m1,R.raw.m2,R.raw.m3,R.raw.m4..... R.raw.m26   
};
```

and these files code

```
if(soundboolvalue==true){
  try {
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.weldon27);    //well done
       mp.start();
       }catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

at the time of creating signed apk , i got the errors are:-

```
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

E:\AndroidStudioExeWorkSpace\AlphabetsZone\app\src\main\java\alpha\logintech\alphabetszone\HardModeActivity.java
Error:(40, 46) error: cannot find symbol variable raw
Error:(40, 55) error: cannot find symbol variable raw
Error:(40, 64) error: cannot find symbol variable raw
.
.
Error:(147, 49) error: cannot find symbol variable raw
Note: E:\AndroidStudioExeWorkSpace\AlphabetsZone\app\src\main\java\alpha\logintech\alphabetszone\Main.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Go to `Build-> Clean Project` and then try to run it.

Comment: Sir i cleaned Project so many times, In emulator app is running successfully , but i got same error at the time of creating signed apk  . I want to upload this app in google play store

Comment: have you find the issue,why this happened ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer is not late. Recently I was facing exactly same issue, I was trying to make an apk release build but I was getting same error message as you. In other side the app is working perfectly in debug mode.
I figured out that my proguard-rules file is missing some rules because I was enabling the obfuscation in the release mode. you have to double check if you proguard-rules is up to date.
before make any update, try first disable the obfuscation from gradle file or by adding -dontobfuscate to your proguard-rules, if the issue will disappear that means you will have to update you gradle file with your own appropriate rules.